# Do not wait for mysql database result in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I tried to get result using mysql database query from called function but do not wait for result in called function. Following is my code for users.js file. I got result in **getBankDetail** function but do not get result in **users** function.

```
var db = require("../db/mysqlconnection");

function users(app){
 app.get("/users",async function(req, res, next){
    let bankDetail = await getBankDetail();
    console.log("bankDetail",bankDetail); //Here I do not got result
    return res.send(bankDetail);
 });
}


async function getBankDetail(){
    db.getConnection(async function(err, connection) {
      if (err) throw err; // not connected!

     await connection.query('SELECT * FROM bank', function (error, results, fields) {
        connection.release();

        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("bank result",results);  //Here I got result
        return results;
      });
    });
}

module.exports = users;
```

My Question is why do not wait for result in called function? I also used async/await functionality.

Comment: Because you are not returning a promise inside getBankDetail and you are also using a callback implementation of query() function instead of promise.

Comment: Can you correct me where I have to change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getBankDetail(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      if (err) reject(err); // not connected!

      connection.query('SELECT * FROM bank', function (error, results, fields) {
        connection.release();

        if (error) reject(err);
        console.log("bank result",results);  //Here I got result
        resolve(results);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And then you can use `let bankDetail = await getBankDetail();`

If you want to use await on your `db.getConnection` and `connection.query` you will have to use **mysql2/promises** library or promisify those functions yourself

Here is the implementation when you use the promisified version of your database driver:

```
async function getBankDetail(){
     const connection = await db.getConnection();
     const data = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM bank');
     connection.release();

     console.log("bank result", data[0]);  //Here I got result

     return data[0];
}
```

Comment: Added more code to show you how you can also use async/await inside getBankDetail for even more readability. For that to work you need to use a database package that supports promises like mysql2/promises or use nodejs util.promisify function to promisify getConnection and query.